# Android rxjava retrofit chain calls not working

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

List item

I very new to RXJava iam using  retrofit to make api via Rxjava flatmaps calls in android. My auth activity divided in three parts in

1. First part make call to login.
2. After successful login get user previous details if he is existing
   user.
3. After then update firebase fcm token to database.

But here only first flatmap only executed remaining flatmap  not executing

here is my code

```
 Auth auth = new Auth();
                auth.setEmail(email);
                auth.setPassword(password);
                authUser.createUser(auth)
                       .flatMap( response -> {
                        //Only this block is executed
                           Log.d("FlatMap1", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                           if(response.code() == 200) {
                               String token = response.body().getToken();
                               editor.putString("token", token);
                               editor.apply();

                               UserId getUser = new UserId();
                               getUser.setUid(firebaseAuth.getUid());
                               return userInfo.CurrentUser("barer " + sharedPreferences.getString("token", null), getUser);

                           }else return null;
                       })
                        .flatMap( response -> {
                           if(!isNew){
                           Log.d("FlatMap1", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                           if(response.code() == 200) {
                              UserInfo userInfo = response.body.UserInfo();

                           }else return null;
                        }else{
                         UpdateFCM updateFCM = new UpdateFCM();
                         updateFCM.setToken(fcmToken);
                         return  updateFcmToken.update("barer 
"+sharedPreferences.getString("token",null),updateFCM);
                        }
                       }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(new Observer<Response<Void>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(Response<Void> voidResponse) {
                                Log.d("FlatMap3",String.valueOf(voidResponse.code()));
                                if(voidResponse.code() == 200){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                            }
                        });
```

So what was wrong
and don't make duplicate and down vote;

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to return **null** values in operator chain from RxJava2. Since you are returning **null**, the whole abruptly breaks and no new elements would be pushed down the stream.

Read this for reference - [RxJava 2.0 does not support Null Values](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls)

Comment: But insted if null i modify by  if(!Boolean.parseBoolean(isNew)){
                                   return userInfo.CurrentUser("barer " + sharedPreferences.getString("auth-token", null), getUser);
                               }else{
                                   return Observable.just(Response.success(400,new UserInfo()));
                               } it also not execting

Comment: What about this check `if(!isNew){` ?

Comment: it is just string  "true" or "false"  if true make api call to get previous info else not call any api and return  Observable.just(Response.success(400,new UserInfo())); } retrofit response  but this way not working

Comment: and without if alse only return api.call also not working

Comment: remove `.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Answer (score 0):

you have to return empty observable instead of return null.

```
if(response.code() == 200) {
   String token = response.body().getToken();
   editor.putString("token", token);
   editor.apply();

   UserId getUser = new UserId();
   getUser.setUid(firebaseAuth.getUid());
   return userInfo.CurrentUser("barer " + sharedPreferences.getString("token", null), getUser);

    } else {

    return Observable.empty();
}
```